# How to find path of a dylib which has been loaded via dlopen API

Tags: c++, c, macos

Lets as a example i have a dylib named as libtest.dylib and i am loading this via dlopen(/usr/local/path/libtest.dylib, RTLD_NOW|RTLD_GLOBAL) with a separate process.

Now inside the libtest.dylib, i have a method called as std::string find_loaded_dylib_path() which should return me the path of the dylib which has been loaded.

Can anybody help me out how can i do that? If you have any sample program that can be great help

Platform: Mac OSX
Language: C++, C

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dladdr()`, which gives information about the image containing a given symbol.
A C solution (which I am more familiar with than C++) could look like this:

```
#include <dlfcn.h>

char *my_dylib_path(void)
{
    Dl_info info;
    if (dladdr(my_dylib_path, &info) != 0) {
        return strdup(info.dli_fname);
    } else {
        // this should not happen :-)
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

The idea is that "my_dylib_path" is a symbol in the dynamic library itself.

I have tested this with a "normal" shared library, but it should work with dynamic library loaded
via `dlopen()` as well.

Comment: Thanks Martin, this worked.. only this instead of function address i put like if (dladdr(__builtin_return_address(0), &dylib_path) != 0) {   //copy the path} else { //Failed to get the path}